Output voltage for synchronous buck converter and synchronous boost converter
I'm reading a book named The Art of Electronics, third edition. The book says:

Just to give a taste of some of the tricks that you can do with
inductors, take a look at Figure 1.52. Although we’ll understand these
circuits a lot better when we go at them in Chapter 9, it’s possible
to see what’s going on with what we know already. In Figure 1.52A the
left-hand side of inductor L is alternately switched between a dc
input voltage Vin and ground, at some rapid rate, spending equal times
connected to each (a “50% duty cycle”). But the defining equation
V=LdI/dt requires that the average voltage across an inductor must be
zero, otherwise the magnitude of its average current is rising without
limit. (This is sometimes called the volt-second balance rule.) From
this it follows that the average output voltage is half the input
voltage (make sure you understand why). In this circuit C2 acts as a
storage capacitor for steadying the output voltage (more on this
later, and in Chapter 9).
Producing an output that is half the voltage of an input is not very
exciting; after all, a simple voltage divider can do that. But, unlike
a voltage divider, this circuit does not waste any energy; apart from
non-idealities of the components, it is 100% efficient. And in fact
this circuit is widely used in power conversion; it’s called a
“synchronous buck converter.”
But look now at Figure 1.52B, which is just a turned around version of
Figure 1.52A. This time, volt-second balance requires that the output
voltage be twice the input voltage. You can’t do that with a voltage
divider! Once again, the output capacitor (C1 this time) serves to
hold the output voltage steady by storing charge. This configuration
is called a “synchronous boost converter.”
These and other switching converters are discussed extensively in
Chapter 9, where Table 9.5 lists some fifty representative types.


I understand that the capacitors in parallel with the DC input voltage source in both circuits provide varying current to the inductor, and that the capacitors in parallel with the output stabilize the output voltage. I also understand the concept of a “50% duty cycle."
I think that in Diagram A, the switch (which might not be described precisely) should initially connect to the upper terminal of the switch (as illustrated in Diagram A) when preparing to charge the inductor. Similarly, in Diagram B, the switch (which might not be described precisely) should initially connect to the lower terminal of the switch when preparing to charge the inductor.
However, I don’t know how to derive (from formula) $$ V_\mathrm{out} = \frac{1}{2}V_\mathrm{in} $$ and $$ V_\mathrm{out} = 2V_\mathrm{in} $$

I don't understand why they installed a capacitor across the input dc source, it has no role in this schematic unless the authors wanted to highlight a potential bidirectionality. You will determine the output voltage or the dc transfer characteristic of these converters by considering that the average voltage across the inductor is zero, at steady-state, along a switching cycle. Please have a look at my seminar on switching converters, the concept is illustrated for each basic switching cell.

@VerbalKint A current that vary along with time will produce voltage on inductor because V=L*(dI)/dt, a constant current will not produce voltage on inductor. Thank you for your PDF, I will see it.

Sorry, I don't understand your comment. What I meant is that the voltage across a perfect inductor on average is zero. Same for the average current in a capacitor, it is zero at steady-state (meaning the converter is stabilized). These are respectfully designated as inductor volt-second balance and capacitor charge balance.

@VerbalKint Sorry for my poor English. As you said, the voltage across a perfect inductor on average is zero and the average current in a capacitor is zero at steady-state, but how can I derive that from formula to get Vout = 1/2 Vin and Vout = 2Vin?

That is the purpose of the seminar link I provided : ) It is explained with illustrations on page 33 for the CCM buck.

@VerbalKint I will see it again.

@VerbalKint In your pdf at page 33, what is voltage multiply time represent?

It represents the area of the graph in volt-seconds or V-s, either positive or negative. It is homogeneous to a flux linkage (see here)

@VerbalKint hi, according to your comment and PDF, I write a answer for this question base at my understand, please see it. Thank you.

@VerbalKint Hi, I updated my answer for this question. I think now it is perfect.

Intuitive explanation:
Let:

Vin = constant
\$D\$ = Switch duty cycle


We're interested in steady state output voltage, which means at the end of the switching cycle, all variables (currents, voltages, stored energy...) are the same as they were at the beginning of the cycle.
During this switching cycle, of duration \$T\$, node "SW" is connected to VIN for a duration \$DT\$, and to GND for a duration \$(1-D)T\$.
Thus average of \$ V_\mathrm{SW} \$ is \$ D \times V_\mathrm{in} \$
For an inductor, \$ e=L\frac{di}{dt} \$, which also means \$ i =\int{\frac{e}{L} dt }\$. In steady state, inductor current is the same at the beginning and end of the switching cycle, which means the integral of voltage across the inductor must be zero. In steady state, average voltage across inductors is zero, and average current through caps is also zero.
So the average of \$ V_\mathrm{out} \$ on the other side of the inductor must be equal to the average of \$ V_\mathrm{SW} \$ ; in other words \$ V_\mathrm{out} = D \times V_\mathrm{in} \$. If there was a difference, current would flow in the inductor to charge or discharge the output cap until its average voltage would become equal to \$ D \times V_\mathrm{in} \$.
Note the boost converter is exactly the same schematic with Vin and Vout swapping places, so the reasoning is the same. Synchronous boost and buck converters are basically the same circuit, they both can transfer power in both directions, the only difference is how the switches are controlled to achieve the desired result.

Hi, thank you for answer, how to get "Thus average of  V_sw is D . V_in"

During time D.T it is connected to Vin so Vsw=Vin, during time (1-D)T it is connected to 0V so Vsw=0V. So its average over period T is D.Vin + (1-D).0V.

You say its average over period T, should be (D.Vin + (1-D).0V) / 2? And what is voltage multiply time represent?

Well average is (integral of voltage)/(time) so D.Vin + (1-D).0V

hi, according to your answer and comment, I write a answer base at my understand for this question, please see it. Thank you.

Hi, I updated my answer for this question. I think now it is perfect.

Thank you for comment and PDF of @VerbalKint, also answer of @bobflux, according to tip of they, I found formula that can simple and clear to understand why author give $$V_\mathrm{out} = \frac{1}{2}V_\mathrm{in}$$ and $$V_\mathrm{out} = 2V_\mathrm{in}$$
From equation about inductor: $$V=L\frac{dI}{dt}$$ we can get $$\Delta I=\frac{V}{L}\Delta t$$
Assume \$D\$ is Switch duty cycle (for example express with like: 50%), \$T\$ is a period that total time of switch ON add switch OFF (for example express with like: 2 second), \$DT\$ is time for switch ON and \$(1-D)T\$ is time for switch OFF.
For buck converter
Now, let us see how to get Vout = 1/2 Vin:
In diagram A, at begin switch connect to upper node of switch, with 50% duty cycle, then switch connect to lower node of switch.
The current cannot suddenly change in inductor, so we can get:
$$\Delta I_\mathrm{switch-on}=\Delta I_\mathrm{switch-off}$$
from circuit we can get:
$$\Delta I_\mathrm{switch-on}=\frac{V_\mathrm{in}-V_\mathrm{out}}{L}DT $$
and $$\Delta I_\mathrm{switch-off}=\frac{V_\mathrm{out}}{L}(1-D)T $$
so we will get $$\frac{V_\mathrm{in}-V_\mathrm{out}}{L}DT=\frac{V_\mathrm{out}}{L}(1-D)T$$
equation both side multiply L will get:
$$(V_\mathrm{in}-V_\mathrm{out})DT=V_\mathrm{out}(1-D)T$$
then equation both side divide \$T\$ will get:
$$(V_\mathrm{in}-V_\mathrm{out})D=V_\mathrm{out}(1-D)$$
simplification get $$V_\mathrm{out}=DV_\mathrm{in}$$
in here, \$D\$ is 50%, namely 1/2, replace \$D\$ with 1/2,
so we get $$V_\mathrm{out} = \frac{1}{2}V_\mathrm{in}$$
For boost converter
As I said, in Diagram B, the switch (which might not be described precisely) should initially connect to the lower terminal of the switch when preparing to charge the inductor.
similarity like buck converter, the current cannot suddenly change in inductor, so we get: $$\Delta I_\mathrm{switch-lower-node}=\Delta I_\mathrm{switch-upper-node}$$
from circuit we can get equation:
$$\Delta I_\mathrm{switch-lower-node}=\frac{V_\mathrm{in}}{L}DT$$
and $$\Delta I_\mathrm{switch-upper-node}=\frac{V_\mathrm{out}-V_\mathrm{in}}{L}(1-D)T$$
so $$\frac{V_\mathrm{in}}{L}DT=\frac{V_\mathrm{out}-V_\mathrm{in}}{L}(1-D)T$$
solve this equation like above by multiply L and divide T at equation both side, we can get $$V_\mathrm{out}=V_\mathrm{in}\frac{1}{1-D}$$
in here, \$D\$ is 50%, namely 1/2, replace \$D\$ with 1/2,
we can get $$V_\mathrm{out} = 2V_\mathrm{in}$$
